# Need to GROUP and COUNT records by a value, then qty > X gets DELETED to a certain qty

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is `ORDER BY` two fieds, `usrid` and `ctoon_id`, `COUNT` the number of `ctoon_id` per `usrid`, and then `DELETE` X records from a specified `usrid` wherever a `ctoon_id` count is greater than 50.

I'm sure there will be nested queries, but I don't have enough experience with SQL to make this work properly. Can someone please help?

Comment: Please show what you've got so far.  It would be helpful for you to post your code.

Comment: Also, why would you want to SORT by columns and then perform a delete? Are these two separate queries?

Comment: I dont know where to begin, so I havent gotten any SQL yet. I suppose you wouldnt really need to SORT at all. You would just need a statement to extract a specific usrid, like DELETE X records WHERE COUNT ctoon_id is > X AND usrid=Y.

So, if usrid has 500 of a specific ctoon_id, and I want all but 50 of those removed from the usrid account to free up some space

Comment: What database system are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, something else? Also, what's the primary key of this table?

Comment: It is in MySQL, and the primary key is usrctoon_id

Answer (score 0):

To delete all records over a count of 50 wherever a ctoon_id count is greater than 50, could you try this query?

**SELECT first, to confirm**

First, run the SELECT, to make sure you're deleting the right records and that the syntax is correct on your database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, ctoon_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        @row_number := CASE
            WHEN @userid = usrid AND @ctoon_id = ctoon_id THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
        END AS rnum,
        @userid:=usrid AS usrid,
        @ctoon_id:=ctoon_id AS ctoon_id
    FROM yourtable
    ORDER BY usrid, ctoon_id
) sub
WHERE rnum > 50;
```

This query will:

1. Run the subquery to find the usrid and ctoon_id values and assign a rownumber to them
2. Select the DISTINCT values which have more than 50 records.

You can run the subquery separately first to see the impacted records.

**DELETE records**

To delete the records, wrap this SELECT in a DELETE query.

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE (usrid, ctoon_id) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT userid, ctoon_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            @row_number := CASE
                WHEN @userid = usrid AND @ctoon_id = ctoon_id THEN @row_number + 1
                ELSE 1
            END AS rnum,
            @userid:=usrid AS usrid,
            @ctoon_id:=ctoon_id AS ctoon_id
        FROM yourtable
        ORDER BY usrid, ctoon_id
    ) sub
    WHERE rnum > 50
);
```

Hope this is OK now.

Comment: Is it deleting all records that have a count greater than 50? I want it to find count > 50 and delete only the records over 50. For instance, if the count is 300 for a specific ctoon_id, it would delete 250 so 50 remains after the query runs.

Comment: Ah, got it. I have misunderstood the question. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: I ran the SELECT by itself, but it spit out an error

#1146 - Table 'collectoons.yourtable' doesn't exist

Comment: Could you try replacing the word "yourtable" with the name of your table that contains this data? I just put "yourtable" because I didn't know what your table name was.

Comment: I completely missed your second instance of the yourtable in the nested statement. So if I only want to prune records from usrid=2034, how would I filter that value in the SELECT?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be incrementing at all when doing the rnum count, so it isn't deleting anything over 50 records of the same ctoon_id [link](http://forums.sqlteam.com/uploads/sqlteam/original/2X/a/ae1e522bf1659de8011fad37600d94b471270995.jpg)[/link]